# openfire not connecting from android genymotion emulator

Tags: android, real-time, openfire, smack

I trying to develop chat demo app using openfire and smack in android.

I setup openfire in my local pc using this following tutorial

[ https://kpblogs.com/mobile-development/android/android-chat-application-using-openfire-server-and-xmpp-smack-client/ ]

here is my code

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public static ConnectivityManager cm;
    public static MyXMPP xmpp;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return new LocalBinder<MyService>(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        xmpp = MyXMPP.getInstance(MyService.this, getString(R.string.server), getString(R.string.user1_login), getString(R.string.user1_password));
        xmpp.connect("onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
                              final int startId) {
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(final Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        xmpp.connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

MyXMPP.java

```
public class MyXMPP {
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public static boolean connected = false;
    public boolean loggedin = false;
    public static boolean isconnecting = false;
    public static boolean isToasted = true;
    private boolean chat_created = false;
    private String serverAddress;
    public static XMPPTCPConnection connection;
    public static String loginUser;
    public static String passwordUser;
    Gson gson;
    MyService context;
    public static MyXMPP instance = null;
    public static boolean instanceCreated = false;

    public MyXMPP(MyService context, String serverAdress, String logiUser,
                  String passwordser) {
        this.serverAddress = serverAdress;
        this.loginUser = logiUser;
        this.passwordUser = passwordser;
        this.context = context;
        init();

    }

    public static MyXMPP getInstance(MyService context, String server,
                                     String user, String pass) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyXMPP(context, server, user, pass);
            instanceCreated = true;
        }
        return instance;

    }

    public org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat Mychat;

    ChatManagerListenerImpl mChatManagerListener;
    MMessageListener mMessageListener;

    String text = "";
    String mMessage = "", mReceiver = "";
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // problem loading reconnection manager
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        gson = new Gson();
        mMessageListener = new MMessageListener(context);
        mChatManagerListener = new ChatManagerListenerImpl();
        initialiseConnection();
    }



    private void initialiseConnection() {

        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        config.setServiceName(serverAddress);
        config.setHost(serverAddress);
        config.setPort(5222);
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
        XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());

        XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
        connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

    }


    public void connect(final String caller) {

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected synchronized Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                if (connection.isConnected())
                    return false;
                isconnecting = true;
                if (isToasted)
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(context, caller + "=>connecting....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                Log.d("Connect() Function", caller + "=>connecting....");

                try {
                    connection.connect();
                    DeliveryReceiptManager dm = DeliveryReceiptManager
                            .getInstanceFor(connection);
                    dm.setAutoReceiptMode(AutoReceiptMode.always);
                    dm.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onReceiptReceived(final String fromid, final String toid, final String msgid, final Stanza packet) {
                        }
                    });
                    connected = true;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (isToasted)
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                                .post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText( context,"(" + caller + ")" + "IOException: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });

                    Log.e("(" + caller + ")", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "(" + caller + ")" + "SMACKException: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    Log.e("(" + caller + ")","SMACKException: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    if (isToasted)
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                                .post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText( context,"(" + caller + ")" + "XMPPException: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                    Log.e("connect(" + caller + ")", "XMPPException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return isconnecting = false;
            }
        };
        connectionThread.execute();
    }

    public void login() {

        try {
            connection.login(loginUser, passwordUser);
            Log.i("LOGIN", "Yey! We're connected to the Xmpp server!");
        } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    private class ChatManagerListenerImpl implements ChatManagerListener {
        @Override
        public void chatCreated(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat,
                                final boolean createdLocally) {
            if (!createdLocally)
                chat.addMessageListener(mMessageListener);
        }

    }

    public void sendMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage) {

        if (!chat_created) {
            Mychat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat(
                    chatMessage.receiver + "@"
                            + context.getString(R.string.server),
                    mMessageListener);
            chat_created = true;
        }
        final Message message = new Message();
        message.setBody(chatMessage.getBody());
        message.setType(Message.Type.normal);

        try {
            if (connection.isAuthenticated()) {
                Mychat.sendMessage(message);
            } else {
                login();
            }
        } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
            Log.e("xmpp.SendMessage()", "msg Not sent!-Not Connected!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class XMPPConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener {
        @Override
        public void connected(final XMPPConnection connection) {
            Log.d("xmpp", "Connected!");
            connected = true;
            if (!connection.isAuthenticated()) {
                login();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosed() {
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "ConnectionCLosed!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionCLosed!");
            connected = false;
            chat_created = false;
            loggedin = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "ConnectionClosedOn Error!!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionClosedOn Error!");
            connected = false;

            chat_created = false;
            loggedin = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {

            Log.d("xmpp", "Reconnectingin " + arg0);

            loggedin = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "ReconnectionFailed!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionFailed!");
            connected = false;

            chat_created = false;
            loggedin = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "REConnected!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionSuccessful");
            connected = true;

            chat_created = false;
            loggedin = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0, boolean arg1) {
            Log.d("xmpp", "Authenticated!");
            loggedin = true;
            ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addChatListener(
                    mChatManagerListener);

            chat_created = false;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();
            if (isToasted)

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Connected!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
        }
    }

    private class MMessageListener implements ChatMessageListener {

        public MMessageListener(Context contxt) {
        }

        @Override
        public void processMessage(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat,
                                   final Message message) {
            Log.i("MyXMPP_MESSAGE_LISTENER", "Xmpp message received: '"
                    + message);

            System.out.println("Body-----"+message.getBody());

            if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat
                    && message.getBody() != null) {
                final ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
                chatMessage.setBody(message.getBody());

                processMessage(chatMessage);
            }
        }

        private void processMessage(final ChatMessage chatMessage) {

            chatMessage.isMine = false;
            Chats.chatlist.add(chatMessage);
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Chats.chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

but when I run my programm I get following error
`SMACKException: The following addresses failed: '192.168.0.9:5222' failed because java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.9 (port 5222) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`

for this error I search many site and also SO but didn't get any solutions.
please help me to solve out this problem.
thankyou in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have `port 5222` in your inbound rules in Advanced firewall settings. Also make sure that your computer is accessible by remote network devices depending on how you test or on what you are testing.

Comment: @Pierre yes I added 5222 in inbound rule of firewall and I am testing on same pc through genymotion emulator

Comment: does it break on this line? `connection.connect();`

Comment: @Pierre no its not break its just show error in logcat only

Comment: Yes because of your try catches... But is that the line which gives you the error? also what is the complete string value of `serverAddress` ?